# Как создать цепочку сети при помощи OpenVPN и Tor на VPS?

Tags: vps, openvpn, tor

Хотелось бы на личном VPS поставить OpenVPN и чтобы сеть проходила через Tor, а я мог подключатся к серверу при помощи SOCKS 5. Т.е. Должна получится вот так цепочка:
Мой Компьютер -> SOCKS 5 -> OpenVPN -> Tor -> Интернет

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день) Можно попробовать связку VPN -> TOR -> VPN с последующей подготовкой конечного сервера к проведению тестов на проникновение. Преимущество такой схемы в том, что наш провайдер (ISP) не видит использования TOR, а конечный сервер, который выступает в качестве контрольного центра, ничего не знает о существовании первого VPN сервера, к которому мы и подключаемся, подробнее можете прочитать здесь) https://codeby.net/threads/anonimnyj-pentest-vpn-tor-vpn.62603/